# what is good starter for trading with bitcoin

Tags: trading, stocks

I would like to try trading with bitcoin, but I am new at trading so I am asking for advise which market pick to get started.

what do I require: 
fast market with lot of trades
no need of huge money input
reliable bitcoin market

I don't know where to start. this will be my bachelor's paper, I am good at math but have no clue how to get started in bitcoin :)

thank you

Comment: It's not really clear whether you're trying to trade Bitcoin or stocks.

Comment: I see. edited. I want only bitcoins

Answer (score 1):

Trading or day-trading BTC is not as easy as it seems. I'd recommend paper trading or trading with a small amount of money until you can develop a profitable strategy.

Use **[Whaleclub](https://whaleclub.co)** for demo trading and trading using BTC only (no dollars or banks).

If you need to buy BTC, look up an exchange in your country at **[Bitcoin.com's Buy Page](https://www.bitcoin.com/buy-bitcoin)**.

Answer (score 1):

I started trading month ago my self, just to like check how it works, and it's grate, i wanted to pick where to put my money in in stocks or in bitcoin/altcoin, of course i chose bitcoin :)

But first learn about bitcoin, learn how wallets work, learn how bitcoin work, learn how bitcoin exchange work, learn,learn,learn.. :)
You have to understand what you want to do, before you do it.

There are lot of grate videos on youtube where you can check other people exp. and tips, and learn from them and start trading your self.. right now i'm exchanging at https://poloniex.com/

Summary: **learn**, **test** with small amount of money, the go in with larger amount.